# Macbook pro hardware failure screen

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, screen

Today I observed:
[image]

Do you have any thoughts on what. I can try to get it fixed? It is a mac book pro 2017 with a GPU.

Comment: You can confirm whether it’s a your hardware software by taking a screen shot.  If the image is clean, it’s your hardware.  Next connect an external screen, if that works it’s your LCD.  My gut says that’s a GPU issue.

Comment: Indeed, a screenshot is clean. But so far I have not heard of any issues in the 2017 series with GPU (notice, both previous macs with GPU burnt through - but due to the class action lawsuit apple had to replace these.)

Comment: Yes, GPU issues aren’t rare since about 2012/2013 but, it doesn’t rule out the “naturally” occurring defects.  Unfortunately, it’s expensive to test the GPU, because you would hook up a known working LCD because that’s going to give you a definitive answer - if the problem goes away, it’s the LCD; if not, it’s the GPU.  you probably have to send it in for service.

Comment: Check out [Rossman](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/) in NYC for repairs (I’m not affiliated), Apple will likely charge double what these guys do.

Comment: I am based in Europe ;)

Comment: He does international too, but that might make it prohibitively expensive.  Maybe send an email and see if he knows anyone in Europe, he’s well connected.